# Functor preserves group objects

Tags: category-theory, functors

Let $C,D$ be finite product categories and $F:C\to D$ be a functor such that it preserves terminal objects and such that it preserves products then $F$ takes group objects of $C$ to group objects of $D$.

I've seen this fact being used but I can't come up with a proof and I can't find any references.

Comment: Have you tried to explicitely show that for a group object $(G,1,m,(-)^{-1})$ the data $(F(G),F(1),F(m),F((-)^{-1}))$ is a group object in $D$?

Comment: This can be proven directly, but follows abstractly from the fact that group objects are models of Lawvere theories, which are preserved by product-preserving functors (essentially by definition).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A group object is an object $G$ together with morphisms $m:G\times G \longrightarrow G$, $u:1\longrightarrow G$ and $i:G\longrightarrow G$ such that some diagrams commute. A functor $F$ satisfying the assumptions turns this into an object $FG$ and morphisms $FG \times FG \cong F(G \times G) \xrightarrow{Fm} FG$, $1\cong F1 \xrightarrow{Fu} FG$ and $Fi: FG \longrightarrow FG$, which still satisfy that the corresponding diagrams commute by functoriality of $F$.